# pyspark.ml random forest model feature importances result empty?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-ml

I am training a `RandomForestClassifier` in `pyspark.ml` and when trying to get the feature importances of the trained model via `featureImportances` attribute of the Estimator, I am seeing nothing in the returned tuple for the feature indices or importance weights:

```
(37,[],[])
```

I'd expect something like...

```
(37,[<feature indices>],[<feature importance weights>])
```

...(certainly not having it just be totally blank). It is odd b/c it appears to recognize that there are 37 features, but does not have any info in the other lists. Nothing in [the docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.featureImportances) seems to address this.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Sparse vector is typically represented in a particular way. If your sparse vector is being printed empty, it likely means that all the values in your sparse vector are zeros.

Checking/printing the `type` of the [RandomForestClassificationModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.html?highlight=featureimportances#pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.featureImportances) Transformer's `featureImportance` attribute, we can see that it is a [SparseVector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.3/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector). In most cases when a sparse vector is printed, you see something like...

```
(<size>, <list of non-zero indices>, <list of non-zero values associated with the indices>)
```

...(if anyone has any links to documents confirming that this is how to interpret a sparse vector, do let me know b/c I can't remember how I know this or where this can be confirmed).

An example of how SparseVectors are printed is shown below:

```py
from  pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
import pprint
a = SparseVector(5,{})
print(a)
# (5,[],[])
pprint.pprint(a)
# SparseVector(5, {})
pprint.pprint(a.toArray())
# array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
 
 
b = SparseVector(5,{0:1, 2:3, 4:5})
print(b)
# (5,[0,2,4],[1.0,3.0,5.0])
pprint.pprint(b)
# SparseVector(5, {0: 1.0, 2: 3.0, 4: 5.0})
pprint.pprint(b.toArray())
# array([1., 0., 3., 0., 5.])
```

So if you are getting a sparse vector like `(<size>, [], [])` for your `featureImportances`, (I'm pretty sure) it means that the Estimator did not find any of your features particularly important (ie. sadly, your/my chosen features are not very good (at least from the Estimator's POV) and more data analysis is in order).

Comment: Related issues for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59209051/8236733, https://github.com/parrt/random-forest-importances/issues/12#issuecomment-444699793